# Confusion on resolve gesture conflict

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am now trying to resolve the conflict of gesture and DrawLayout.
According to the [document](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav#conflicting-gestures), to resolve the conflict, I should call `DrawerLayout.setSystemGestureExclusionRects` to specify the exclusion area Rect.

So I write the code like this:

```
override fun onDraw(c: Canvas?) {
    super.onDraw(c)

    updateGestureExclusion()
}

override fun onLayout(changed: Boolean, l: Int, t: Int, r: Int, b: Int) {
    super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b)

    if (!changed) {
        return
    }
    updateGestureExclusion()
}

private fun updateGestureExclusion() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        return
    }

    systemGestureExclusionRects = listOf(createSystemGestureExclusionRect())
}

private fun createSystemGestureExclusionRect(): Rect {
    val screenSize = ScreenUtils.getScreenSize()
    val height = screenSize.y
    val heightInDp = SizeUtils.px2dp(height.toFloat())

    return if (heightInDp <= 200) {
        Rect(0, 0, SizeUtils.dp2px(56f), height)
    } else {
        val topInDp = (heightInDp - 200) / 2f
        val top = SizeUtils.dp2px(topInDp)
        val bottom = top + SizeUtils.dp2px(199f)
        Rect(0, top, SizeUtils.dp2px(56f), bottom)
    }
}
```

I clip an 56dp * 200dp at the center-left of screen as systemGestureExclusionRect. Unforetunately, For `Realme RMX2020` device, Android System recognize the area of left-top screen as systemGestureExclusionRect. Even if I change the `exclusionRect`, Android System still recognize the area of left-top screen as systemGestureExclusionRect.

I also checked the size of the rect area and it did not exceed the limit in the [document](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav#back-gestures).

What's wrong with my code and how to resolve the conflict correctly? Thank you! :)